# How to reset or remove owner of a OTRS ticket?

Tags: otrs

Is there any way to remove the owner of a ticket?

I want to be able to remove the owner in following cases:

- ticket closed

  => owner shall be none
- ticket was answered by a specific person, but the next operation shall be handled by the full team

  => owner shall be none after the person has set the ticket into a specific state?

I have tried to use already the generic agent, but the GenericAgent is only able to set a specific agent, not to reset it. Or do I not understand something well?
Preferably I want to have the option in the generic agent, so I can automate some tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set owner to system user "Admin OTRS" aka "root@localhost", for example via Perl API. [ getUserID(), TicketOwnerSet() ]

"next operation shall be handled by the full team" - this happens automatically when the ticket gets unlocked. And then you have lock timeouts to automatically unlock.